# Empty title on Community Promotion Ads statistic page

Tags: bug, status-completed, title, open-source-advertising

The title on the stats page for Community Promotion Ads is empty:

```
<title></title>
```

Examples: [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3709) and [Web Applications](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2554).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, it'll now say "Community Promotion Ad Statistics"